# WPAlchemy - Fatal Error on line 3

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I have some sort of error on line 3 of my code and I can't seem to figure it out. Below is the error that it's outputting and also my code.

Fatal error: Call to a member function the_meta() on a non-object on line 3

```
<?php $meta = $custom_metabox->the_meta('description', TRUE); 
if (!empty($meta)): 
echo '<p class="description">'.$meta['description'].'</p>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<br>

<ul id="process"><span>Process: </span></ul>

<br>

<ul class="credits">
<?php if(the_meta()) { the_meta(); } ?>
    <li class="shorturl"><span>Short Url: </span>
        <div id="d_clip_container">
            <input id="fe_text" onChange="clip.setText(this.value)" type="text" value="<?php echo bitly(); ?>" />
        <div id="d_clip_button" class="my_clip_button"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="save"><span>Save: </span> <a class="gimmebar" href="#">Gimme Bar</a></li>                
</ul>
</div> <!-- End Info -->

<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

This is line 3
    `<?php $meta = $custom_metabox->the_meta('description', TRUE);`

Comment: The answer is there in the error message - `$custom_metabox` isn't an object. Where is it defined?

Comment: make sure that the class or object that $meta is referencing is included/loaded

Comment: It's a plugin I am using and it only throws an error when I'm on a search page. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: what wordpress template file did you put this in?

Comment: I am using WPAlchemy for my custom meta box. This plugin goes in the directory right before the themes folder (/wp-content/wpalchemy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing something in your code.. Look at line 3 : `$custom_metabox->the_meta('description', TRUE)`.. Now look at the line 13 : `if(the_meta()) { the_meta(); }` In a part of your code you have used the `the_meta()` as a member function and in another part you have used it as a general function.. How can this be right? First make sure if the `the_meta()` is in a class or not than call it properly...

UPDATE:

Ok some searching in the wpalchemy manual and I got what the problem is.. you should construct the `$custom_metabox` as a `WPAlchemy_MetaBox` in your `functions.php` to be able to include the metabox in a template.. [Read Here](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox)..

Sample:

```
$custom_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'My Custom Meta',
    'template' => STYLESHEETPATH . '/custom/meta.php'
));
```

And when you have that now you should include the functions in your template...

Sample code as provided in the manual:

```
// usually needed
global $custom_metabox;

// get the meta data for the current post
$custom_metabox->the_meta();

// set current field, then get value
$custom_metabox->the_field('name');
$custom_metabox->the_value();

// get value directly
$custom_metabox->the_value('description');

// loop a set of fields
while($custom_metabox->have_fields('authors'))
{
    $custom_metabox->the_value();
}

// loop a set of field groups
while($custom_metabox->have_fields('links'))
{
    $custom_metabox->the_value('title');

    $custom_metabox->the_value('url');

    if ($custom_metabox->get_the_value('nofollow')) echo 'is-nofollow';

    $custom_metabox->the_value('target');
}
```

*** Note the `global $custom_metabox;` at the top** 
** Also you should use it like `$custom_metabox->the_meta();` not just plain `the_meta();`..

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to go about that as I'm nowhere near a developer. Plus, I'm pretty sure when I pasted this code, it was provided by the Plugin Author.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look at all that for me, Miro. Really appreciate it. I'll go through it and accept your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I ended up following this [tutorial](http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/) and got it working. Thanks for your help